# `"Key "0" in object with ArrayAccess of class does not exist` error after change of computer

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, relational-database

I changed my computer and tried to import my project to my new computer.

I use Symfony (6 on my old PC and 7 on my new one). I used Doctrine to recreate the database locally before importing all data. In the project a Book has Authors and an Editor.

Why do I get error `"Key "0" in object with ArrayAccess of class "Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection" does not exist.`?

Even though it loads all the data, the Collection of Authors is empty, and for the Editor, I have:

```
-lazyObjectState: Symfony\Component\VarExporter\Internal\LazyObjectState {#1038 ▼
        +status: UNINITIALIZED_FULL
```

My relations are mapped. I don't have this problem on my old PC.

Entities:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\LibrisRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Types;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: LibrisRepository::class)]
#[ORM\Table("exlibris")]
class Libris implements \JsonSerializable
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    [...]

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(inversedBy: 'libris')]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false)]
    private ?Editeur $editeur = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity: Auteur::class, inversedBy: 'libris')]
    private Collection $auteurs;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 100, nullable: true)]
    private ?string $xl_img = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 50)]
    private ?string $xl_livre = null; /*nom du Libris*/

    #[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'libris', targetEntity: BDConcern::class)]
    private Collection $bdConcernes;
```

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\AuteurRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: AuteurRepository::class)]
class Auteur implements \JsonSerializable
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 30)]
    private ?string $nom = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 30, nullable: true)]
    private ?string $prenom = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity: Libris::class, mappedBy: 'auteurs')]
    private Collection $libris;
```

Got the error here :

```
    {% for l in listL %}
            [...]
                {{ l.auteurs[0].prenom }} {{ l.auteurs[0].nom }}</p>
            [...]
    {% endfor %}
```

[dd of listL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oyacS.png)

AccueilController:

```
$listL = $libRepo->findAccRecent();
```

libRepo :

```
public function findAccRecent(): array
   {
        $etats = [1, 2];

    return $this->createQueryBuilder('l')
           ->andWhere('l.xl_etat IN (:etat)')
           ->setParameter('etat', $etats)
           ->orderBy('l.xl_date', 'DESC')
           ->setMaxResults(18)
           ->getQuery()
           ->getResult();
   }
```